# Running background asp web service

Tags: asp.net, web, service

I am building a web service in asp.net and have to create background tasks that connect to the database on both continuous and scheduled events. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by continous and scheduled events? a web service is a method that is triggerd each time a consumer calls your web service. creating a web service is very easy,Explain more your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to roll your own scheduler, you might consider looking at Hangfire: http://hangfire.io/.

Comment: Thanks @Justin, just finished part of the windows service and it's working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You may choose to create a simple Windows service using the Visual Studio Project Create wizard and choose `File->New->Project->Windows Service.` Write your database connectivity logic in the `Service1.cs` (you may rename it to what ever you want). And then use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule to run the service at your feasible time. Thats all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks. @Iman I have to run a background task in that web service that connects to the database.